# spring boot return Not Found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to create a rest method to get a client by id in postman, I even created the method, but it doesn't return any information by id with spring boot.

ClientControle.java:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/clientes/{id}")
public Cliente listCliente(@PathVariable("id") long id){
    return clienteService.getById(id);
```

ClienteService:

```
public interface ClienteService {
    
    Cliente getById(long id);
    
    List<Cliente> getAll();
    
    Cliente save(Cliente cliente);

}
```

but i have the following error:

[image]

Comment: From where Service is getting data? Is that IS available there?

Comment: ClienteService is an interface. Do you have a implementation of the class? Also need to have a Repository interface.

Comment: could you share the console, it seems the server is not found that api, and share the repository also

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional information _as text_, not images

Comment: service is getting data With H2 Database spring boot

Answer (score 1):

You have `@RequestMapping("clientes")` at the controller(class) level,
so your actual URL should be `http://localhost:8080/clientes/clientes/1`

Comment: I tried with this url and it didn't work, but with the url http://localhost:8080/clientes
bring me all but i would like to bring only one by id and not all

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As per your code in image, you shared you are having `clientes` on class level also 
either you can remove from here then `localhost:8080/clientes/1` will work
 or you need to use `localhost:8080/clientes/clientes/1`

Comment: @MikelPintto Can you share the log or screenshot of what error you are getting now?

Comment: "message": "Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.mikelspring.crm.model.Cliente$HibernateProxy$a9UNnqeE[\"hibernateLazyInitializer\"])",
    "path": "/clientes/clientes/1"
}

Comment: @MikelPintto It seems the actual question answered because now it will not 404 so you can accept and ask a new questions with more detail regarding the log you shared here.

Comment: service is getting data With H2 Database spring boot

Comment: @MikelPintto The issue now you are mentioning is related to spring data, not spring rest and this question is dedicated to spring rest.